# SQL EXISTS Operator never returns True

Tags: php, sql

i`ve got a sql Table named "pwt" with the columns "usr" and "pw".
There is only one entry with the values "admin" and "chat".

I get 2 values transfered via a php-form. Now should I compare the given values with the two in the sql table, and if they`re both right ("admin" and "chat"), than should the script redirect to another site, otherwise it should echo "password incorrect"

I know that this isn`t a real password mechanism, but it just runs on a virtual machine, and i just want to get the mechanism working.

This is the code:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "chat";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$us1 = $_GET["user"];
$pw1 = $_GET["pswd"];

// sql for compare record
$sql = "SELECT usr, pw FROM pwt WHERE EXISTS (SELECT usr, pw FROM pwt WHERE usr = '$us1' AND pw = '$pw1')"; 



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: http://192.168.56.101/testat/source/admin.php');
} else {
    echo "Falsches Passwort " . $conn->error;
    echo "Passwort ist $pw1";
    echo "Name ist $us1";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks so far.

Comment: You are missing the `WHERE`.  You should check your error messages.

Comment: Oh sorry was the wrong version of the code, the WHERE is included before the EXISTS. I dont get any error messages, everything works fine, but it doesn`t redirect to the page. Therefore there has to be a problem with the SQL request. EDIT: I just edited the code

Comment: Do you need exists? Wouldn't `WHERE usr = '$us1' AND pw = '$pw1'` be enough? (Also not a good practice exercise, should use parameterized query, and really be hashing the password)

Answer (score 0):

This query function

```
$conn->query($sql)
```

only returns false if your query failed (as in error). You want to check if you actually get results. Try

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('Location: http://192.168.56.101/testat/source/admin.php');
} else {
    echo "Falsches Passwort " . $conn->error;
    echo "Passwort ist $pw1";
    echo "Name ist $us1";
}
```

Aside from that, you should just use this query in stead since yours should return every single row from pwt when the exist clause is true even just for one row:

```
$sql = "SELECT usr, pw FROM pwt WHERE usr = '$us1' AND pw = '$pw1'";
```

Comment: Still no change :(, the only result i`m getting is the three last "echo" with the correct values at "Passwort ist" and "Name ist".

Comment: why don't you echo the $sql and see what the actual query is that you're posting. Put that in to mysql directly and see what it says

Comment: when i echo $sql, than it just shows the "SELECT usr, pw FROM.... with the correct values, and when i echo $result, than it`s just empty

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue

```
// sql for compare record
$sql = "SELECT usr, pw FROM pwt WHERE EXISTS (SELECT usr, pw FROM pwt WHERE usr = '$us1' AND pw = '$pw1')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    header('Location: http://192.168.56.101/testat/source/admin.php');
```

This works fine :), Thank you all for your help.